# Bitmap size exceeds VM budget after second load

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

This is driving me crazy. I have a game which has a bitmap as the background, this is big so I scale it down and this works fine. However when I navigate to another activity and then reload the game screen it crashes on drawing the background. I am calling recycle on all the bitmaps and setting them to null on onDestroy() but this doesn't help.

Any ideas and if not how can I debug the memory to see at which step its growing. I looked at getting the heap but nothing of any size is on there really.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use bitmap.recycle() instantly after bitmap is not needed.

Comment: turn on StrictMode to see in LogCat more info about possible memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks mate!!! onDestroy wasn't running for some reason. Moved it to before I call the next activity and now it works fine. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

You can use MAT analyzer for checking memory issue, this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseMemoryAnalyzer/article.html) will help you

Answer (score 1):

When you jump from one activity A to another B, A doesnt finish and resources are still in memoery, there are 3 solutions for this.

1. When calling activity B, you may finish activity A.
2. Use WeakRefrences for bitmaps so the gc can rid of unused resouces
   and reload them onResume.
3. remove refrences of the bitmaps onPause() and load them onResume()

Comment: Does this mean that when I call activity B the onDestroy is not called on activity A? This is what was happening in my case by the looks of things

Comment: Use onPause() rather than onDestroy() as you dont know when android is going to destroy the activity have a look here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

Comment: Follow the solution provide by Warlock, its a perfect

Comment: Shouldn't activity A be destroyed, when jumped from A to B and B is running out of memory?

Comment: this case works for applications with no active activities, but not activities inside your own app